# Bounds for cyclotomic polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, cyclotomic-polynomials

Whilst going through online forums, I found [this](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?p=634797) thread post, which claims

> For $n\in Z >1$, $$S\cdot n^{\phi(r)} \leq \Phi_r(n)\leq \frac{1}{S}\cdot n^{\phi(r)}$$
> where $ S = \prod_{m=1}^{\infty} (1-n^{-m})$

Apparently it should be easy to prove these bounds, but I am really struggling here. I simply can not make any progress.

I do know it has something to do with the following definition:

$$\Phi_r(n) = \prod_{d | r} (n^d-1)^{\mu(\frac{r}{d})} $$

Regardless I do not know how to approach this. I have never seen a similar result in any textbook or wikipedia. I would be thankful if someone could prove/disprove this.

Comment: Since $\deg\Phi_r = \phi(r)$, $\Phi_r(n) / n^{\phi(n)} = \prod_{d \mid r} (1 - n^{-d})^{\mu(r/d)}$. Each of the factors $1 - n^{-d}$ is between $0$ and $1$, while $\mu(r/d) \in \{+1,-1,0\}$. You get an upper bound just by replacing all the $\mu$'s with $-1$'s, and a lower bound by replacing them with $+1$'s. Then you get even worse upper and lower bounds by just taking all $d$ instead of just those dividing $r$.

Comment: Thanks. That was easier to show than I thought. Can you please convert the comment into an answer, so I may accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeated from comment: Since $\deg \Phi_r = \phi(r)$, $$\Phi_r(n) / n^{\phi(r)} = \prod_{d \mid r} (1 - n^{-d})^{\mu(r/d)}.$$ Each of the factors $1 - n^{-d}$ is between $0$ and $1$, while $\mu(r/d) \in \{+1, -1, 0\}$.
You get an upper bound just by replacing all the $\mu$'s with $-1$'s, and a lower bound by replacing all the $\mu$'s with $+1$'s. You get even worse upper and lower bounds by ignoring the restriction $d \mid r$.